# Can't Location Ref from submodule

Tags: git-submodules

I'm working on finalizing the install script of my dotfiles. I use a submodule called dotbot and I'm trying to fix an issue with the git submodule.

Currently I'm running the following command in my setup script.

`git submodule update --recursive --remote --init`

and when it runs in my install script it gives me the folowing error.

`fatal: Unable to find refs/remotes/origin/HEAD revision in submodule path 'submodules/dotbot'`

I have cd into the submodule and updated the package and see that the latest commit hash matches what I have so I don't understand what hte problem is.

Anyone have experience?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Git on Windows? I’m noticing the error is similar to what was mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76368485/in-git-what-may-cause-the-error-message-fatal-unable-to-find-refs-remotes-or).

From my answer there…

You can run `git show-ref` to see all the references the submodule has when you change directory (cd) to it. I also usually run `git fetch -pv` to make sure I’m seeing what’s on the remote server (the -p flag prunes stale references that no longer exist on the remote).

The `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` is a symbolic reference that denotes the latest commit on the default branch on the remote. If you run `git show-ref` from within either submodule you *should* see `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` listed - if not, something may be wrong with your repository.

The `--remote` flag instructs `git-submodule update` to update the submodule to the remote tracking branch. If you don’t have one specified in `.gitmodules` (or in config), it updates the submodule to the default remote HEAD, which is `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`.