# In git, what may cause the error message " fatal: Unable to find refs/remotes/origin/HEAD revision in submodule path 'Assets/NRSDK'"

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

Example project:

https://github.com/hpvdt/HMD-nreal/tree/cleanup/dev1

When I checkout this project and try to synchronise with all its submodule, I got a very concerning error message:

```bash
git submodule update --remote --recursive
fatal: Unable to find refs/remotes/origin/HEAD revision in 
submodule path 'Assets/NRSDK'
```

It is concerning because `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` is not a revision, nor it is a branch name.

What could possibly cause this defect? Is it a bug in git? I'm using git version 2.40.1.windows.1.

Comment: `origin/HEAD` isn’t a strange thing to have in `refs/`.

Comment: I'm so sorry I forgot to copy branch name, now added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a submodule acts like a standalone repository once you are inside it, you can test the submodules directly.
If you change directory (cd) to Assets/NRSDK while on the cleanup/dev1 branch of your super project, you can run `git show-ref` to see all the references it has. I also usually run `git fetch -pv` to make sure I’m seeing what’s on the remote server (the -p flag prunes stale references that no longer exist on the remote).

The `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` is a symbolic reference that denotes the latest commit on the default branch on the remote. If you run `git show-ref` from within either submodule you *should* see `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` listed - if not, something may be wrong with your repository.

The `--remote` flag instructs `git-submodule update` to update the submodule to the remote tracking branch. If you don’t have one specified in `.gitmodules` (or in config), it updates the submodule to the default remote HEAD, which is `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`.

Comment: I have tested the repository using Git VERSION 2.40.0 on FreeBSD, and 2.38.0.windows.1 on Windows 10. I have not been able to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the repository structure - taken when the question was asked.

[image]

- From this screenshot you can see that there is no submodules under this project.
- The relevant folder from your question is not a submodule as well, its simple a directory

[image]

So it's not clear what are your required submodules.

Comment: The Q was updated. The shown branch split the monorepo into submodules.